# How to make a dropdown login menu in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make a dropdown login/register form in html/css i want it to dropdown from my navbar that i have already created but i cant get it to work properly can anyone give me some pointers and tell me what i am doing wrong

here is a jsfiddle of my page i am creating
https://jsfiddle.net/nikhendricks43/cqod7p57/#&togetherjs=lxPBaomiBb

or here is my code:

:html

```
  <title>MVBT FFA Chapter</title>
 <head>


 </head>




 <div id="header">
<a id="addpost"href="editnews.html">+</a>
      <center><img src="ffaheader.png" alt-"ffa header image" width="70%"       height="40%"></center>
 </div>

  <div id="nav">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/donate.html">Donate</a></li>
    <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/about.html">About</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="dropdown()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
   <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
 <input type="text" placeholder="email">
 <p>Password<p>
 <br/>
 <input type="password" placeholder="password">
   </div>
 </div>





 </body>
 </html>

  <script>
  function dropdown() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }    
  </script>
  </ul>









  <body>









 </div>

  <body bgcolor="grey">


       <div id="bodydiv">

          <iframe src="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/newscontent.html"></iframe>




      </div>



  </body>  




   </html>
```

and here is my css:

```
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }

    .dropdown {

        align-content:  right;
        position: relative;

    }

    .dropdown-content {
         width: 1000px;
        height: 500px;
        padding:5px;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color:  blue;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: blue}

    .show {display:block;}

    #sidebarleft{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;


    }
        #addpost{
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
        #addpost:hover{
          font-size: 20px;
          color:grey;

        }

        #newsframe{
           padding-left:20%;
           width:65%;
           height:100%;
           border:10px;

    }

     #header{
         background: #fcec5d;


      }







    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #fbec5d;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    }


    #nav{
    width:100%;
    height:46px;
    background:#fbec5d;
    }
    #headerimage{
        width:100%;
        height:35%;
        display:flex;

   }
   #bodydiv{

        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:blue;
        display:flex;




 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[See this fiddle I made based on your code](https://jsfiddle.net/d5r6y5xw/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/events.html">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/donate.html">Donate</a></li>
  <li><a href="file:///E:/ffachapterpage/about.html">About</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Your dropdown text</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <label class="margin-bottom-5">Email: <label><br>
       <input class="margin-bottom-5" type="text" placeholder="email"><br>
       <label class="margin-bottom-5">Password: <label><br>
       <input class="margin-bottom-5" type="password" placeholder="password"><br>
       <input class="margin-bottom-5" type="submit" value="Connect"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* When the .dropdown div gets hovered, 
we change the display property of the dropdown
content in order for it to be shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


/* "An element with position: relative; 
is positioned relative to its normal position" */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/*"An element with position: absolute; is positioned 
relative to the nearest positioned ancestor"
In this case, it's positioned relative to the 
.dropdown div. I then played with the
left and top properties in order to align it properly
*/
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:46px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    border:1px solid black;
}

/*Under this comment, it's mostly for styles. You can ignore what's below*/
a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
 }

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropdown{
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover{
    background-color: grey;
}

.margin-bottom-5 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i think this is what i am looking for

Comment: Sorry to bother you but there is one problem  when i hover over the dropdown part it is shown behind the divs i have set up for my site and i cant see it at all does it have anything to do with the z-index maybe i am fairly new to html/css

Comment: Does the div you set up have a bigger z-index than 1 ? Post an edit on your post with an updated fiddle